# In Lightroom, how can I move a set of filtered images preserving the folder order?

Tags: lightroom, workflow

I'd like to move all my raw (.nef) files in my Lightroom catalog to another hard drive to free up space.  However, I want to preserve the folder structure from the source drive to the other hard drive.  Additionally, I'd like to preserve my non-destructive edits I made on those images and history.

Currently I have one catalog that spans two hard drives.  I import photos on the main drive, work on them, and when I'm finished I'd like to easily move them to the second.

I can easily filter the ones I want, but I cannot seem to preserve the folder structure when moving between the two drives.  I could do things folder by folder, but that will take too long.  Finally, I can do a vanilla export and delete, but I will lose edits and I'm not sure I can preserve the folder structure I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I found a simpler solution [here](http://www.lightroomforums.net/showthread.php?13839-Move-Photos-to-External-Hardrive).

1. In your Lightroom catalogue, in Folders, click the + and add a new folder on the new drive.
2. Still in Lightroom, now drag folders from    your existing hard drive and drop them on the new drive.

---

**To copy your photos to another drive:**

1. Apply the filters that you want.
2. Select all the filtered photos.
3. Goto **File**->**Export as Catalog**.
4. Keep "**Export selected files only**" and "**Export negative files**" checked.
5. Specify a path in your other hard drive.
6. Wait for it to make a copy of all your files.

---

**To use these copied photos in Lightroom:**

1. Goto **File**->**Open Catalog**.
2. Select the newly created catalog on your other drive.

---

This will meet the following of your requirements:

- Preserve your folder structure.
- Maintain your non-destructive edits and history.

Comment: Thanks Abhimanyu.  Is there a way to keep everything in one catalog?  When travelling, I like the fact I can preserve the rendered previews in the original catalog, even if I can't view the original.

Comment: Please see the updated answer for a simpler solution that I found online.

Comment: Thanks for the research; that method will only work if I want to move all the images in that folder to the new drive.  In my case, I only want to move a subset.  For each folder, there are about 10% of images I want to keep on the main drive; the rest I want to move onto a new drive.  Like I said, I can do this one by one, but I have hundreds folders.  I'd like to automate.  Your original method works well, except I want everything in the same catalog.

Comment: That's easy. After exporting, goto "Import from Catalog", point it to your new catalog and select "Add New Photos To Catalog Without Moving". This will consolidate everything in a single catalog while moving some photos to an external drive.